# BST implementation for insert and search in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am doing this implementation in JavaScript that I was asked to solve. I would like to get some code review.

```
/**
 *   Binary Search Tree
 *
 *  TreeNode class
 *
 *             Create a TreeNode class
 *             The TreeNode class should contain the following properties:
 *
 *
 *
 *  BinarySearchTree class.
 *
 *             Create a BinarySearchTree class
 *
 *             The BinarySearchTree class should contain the following
 *             properties:
 *
 *                    root:   A pointer to the root node (initially null)
 *                    size:   The number of nodes in the BinarySearchTree
 *
 *             The BinarySearchTree class should also contain the following
 *             methods:
 *
 *                  insert:   A method that takes takes an integer value, and
 *                            creates a node with the given input.  The method
 *                            will then find the correct place to add the new
 *                            node. Values larger than the current node node go
 *                            to the right, and smaller values go to the left.
 *
 *                            Input:     value
 *                            Output:    undefined
 *
 *                  search:   A method that will search to see if a node with a
 *                            specified value exists and returns true or false
 */
```

Here's the implementation and unit test:

```
'use strict';


class TreeNode {
  constructor(value = null) {
    this.value = value;
    this.left = this.right = null;
  }
}

class BinarySearchTree {
  constructor() {
    this.root = null;
    this.size = 0;
  }

  // Time Complexity: O(N)
  // Auxiliary Space Complexity: O(N)
  insert(value) {
    if (!this.root) {
      this.root = new TreeNode(value);
      this.size++;
      return;
    }
    else {

      let currentNode = this.root;
      let newNode = new TreeNode(value); 
      while (currentNode) {
        if (value < currentNode.value) {
          if (currentNode.left) {
            currentNode = currentNode.left;
          }
          else {
            currentNode.left = newNode;
            this.size++;
            break;
          }
        }
        else {
          if (currentNode.right) {
            currentNode = currentNode.right;
          }
          else {
            currentNode.right = newNode;
            this.size++;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }


  // Time Complexity: O(N)
  // Auxiliary Space Complexity: O(N)

  search(value) {
    if (!this.root) {
      return false;
    }
    let currentNode = this.root;
    if (currentNode.value === value) {
      return true;
    }

    while (currentNode) {
      if (value < currentNode.value) {
        if (currentNode.left) {
          currentNode = currentNode.left;
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      else if (value > currentNode.value) {
        if (currentNode.right) {
          currentNode = currentNode.right;
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}




////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////  DO NOT TOUCH TEST BELOW!!!  ///////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


console.log('TreeNode Class');
let testCount = [0, 0];

assert(testCount, 'able to create an instance', () => {
  let node = new TreeNode();
  return typeof node === 'object';
});

assert(testCount, 'has value property', () => {
  let node = new TreeNode();
  return node.hasOwnProperty('value');
});

assert(testCount, 'has left property', () => {
  let node = new TreeNode();
  return node.hasOwnProperty('left');
});

assert(testCount, 'has right property', () => {
  let node = new TreeNode();
  return node.hasOwnProperty('right');
});

assert(testCount, 'has default value set to null', () => {
  let node = new TreeNode();
  return node.value === null;
});

assert(testCount, 'able to assign a value upon instantiation', () => {
  let node = new TreeNode(5);
  return node.value === 5;
});

assert(testCount, 'able to reassign a value', () => {
  let node = new TreeNode();
  node.value = 5;
  return node.value === 5;
});

assert(testCount, 'able to point to left child node', () => {
  let node1 = new TreeNode(5);
  let node2 = new TreeNode(10);
  node1.left = node2;
  return node1.left.value === 10;
});

assert(testCount, 'able to point to right child node', () => {
  let node1 = new TreeNode(5);
  let node2 = new TreeNode(10);
  node1.right = node2;
  return node1.right.value === 10;
});

console.log('PASSED: ' + testCount[0] + ' / ' + testCount[1], '\n\n');


console.log('Binary Search Tree Class');
testCount = [0, 0];

assert(testCount, 'able to create an instance', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  return typeof bst === 'object';
});

assert(testCount, 'has root property', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  return bst.hasOwnProperty('root');
});

assert(testCount, 'has size property', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  return bst.hasOwnProperty('size');
});

assert(testCount, 'default root set to null', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  return bst.root === null;
});

assert(testCount, 'default size set to zero', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  return bst.size === 0;
});

console.log('PASSED: ' + testCount[0] + ' / ' + testCount[1], '\n\n');


console.log('BinarySearchTree Insert Method');
testCount = [0, 0];

assert(testCount, 'has insert method', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  return Object.prototype.toString.apply(bst.insert) === '[object Function]';
});

assert(testCount, 'able to insert a node into empty binary search tree', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  bst.insert(5);
  return bst.size === 1 && bst.root.value === 5;
});

assert(testCount, 'able to insert node to left of root node', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  bst.insert(5);
  bst.insert(3);
  return bst.size === 2 && bst.root.value === 5 && bst.root.left.value === 3;
});

assert(testCount, 'able to insert node to right of node left of root node', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  bst.insert(5);
  bst.insert(3);
  bst.insert(4);
  return bst.size === 3 && bst.root.value === 5 && bst.root.left.value === 3 &&
    bst.root.left.right.value === 4;
});

assert(testCount, 'able to insert node to right of root node', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  bst.insert(5);
  bst.insert(8);
  return bst.size === 2 && bst.root.value === 5 && bst.root.right.value === 8;
});

assert(testCount, 'able to insert node to left of node right of root node', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  bst.insert(5);
  bst.insert(8);
  bst.insert(7);
  return bst.size === 3 && bst.root.value === 5 && bst.root.right.value === 8 &&
    bst.root.right.left.value === 7;
});

console.log('PASSED: ' + testCount[0] + ' / ' + testCount[1], '\n\n');


console.log('BinarySearchTree Search Method');
testCount = [0, 0];

assert(testCount, 'has search method', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  return Object.prototype.toString.apply(bst.search) === '[object Function]';
});

assert(testCount, 'returns true when element exists in binary search tree', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  bst.insert(5);
  bst.insert(3);
  bst.insert(8);
  bst.insert(4);
  bst.insert(7);
  return bst.search(4) === true;
});

assert(testCount, 'returns false when element does not exist in binary search tree', () => {
  let bst = new BinarySearchTree();
  bst.insert(5);
  bst.insert(3);
  bst.insert(8);
  bst.insert(4);
  bst.insert(7);
  return bst.search(10) === false;
});

console.log('PASSED: ' + testCount[0] + ' / ' + testCount[1], '\n\n');


// custom assert function to handle tests
// input: count {Array} - keeps track out how many tests pass and how many total
//        in the form of a two item array i.e., [0, 0]
// input: name {String} - describes the test
// input: test {Function} - performs a set of operations and returns a boolean
//        indicating if test passed
// output: {undefined}
function assert(count, name, test) {
  if(!count || !Array.isArray(count) || count.length !== 2) {
    count = [0, '*'];
  } else {
    count[1]++;
  }

  let pass = 'false';
  let errMsg = null;
  try {
    if (test()) {
      pass = ' true';
      count[0]++;
    }
  } catch(e) {
    errMsg = e;
  }
  console.log('  ' + (count[1] + ')   ').slice(0,5) + pass + ' : ' + name);
  if (errMsg !== null) {
    console.log('       ' + errMsg + '\n');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `search` function can be simpler.

- The special treatment for `this.root` is unnecessary. If you drop the conditional on `this.root`, and on `currentNode.value === value`, the loop will naturally handle it.
- Inside the loop, the conditionals on `currentNode.left` and `currentNode.right` are unnecessary. For example when `value < currentNode.value`, you can go ahead and assign `currentNode = currentNode.left`, if the value is `null` then the loop will terminate and execution correctly reaches `return false`.

Like this:

```
  search(value) {
    let currentNode = this.root;

    while (currentNode) {
      if (value < currentNode.value) {
          currentNode = currentNode.left;
      }
      else if (value > currentNode.value) {
          currentNode = currentNode.right;
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, a comment says:

```
// Time Complexity: O(N)
// Auxiliary Space Complexity: O(N)
```

For binary search trees, the complexity is usually much lower. Also, strictly speaking, you always have to define what your `N` ist. I'd rather write it as:

```
// Time complexity: O(log(size))
// Auxiliary space complexity: O(1)
```

A single `insert` call needs either 0 or 1 new node. Therefore, the space complexity is constant.

The average time complexity is \$\mathcal O(\log(\textit{size}))\$ since typical binary trees split into two halves that have about the same size. There are corner cases (like inserting a sorted sequence) where the binary tree has only one of the branches (left or right) filled; in that case the time complexity is \$\mathcal O(\textit{size})\$.

To avoid this worst-case complexity, you can later refine your class to implement a [self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree).